# how to secure documents with personal DRM

Tags: drm

Is it possible to secure my own documents with some kind of DRM so that they can only be read by a specific person?

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the documents with a public key (e.g. from `gpg`) of the specific person. That will result in a document readable only by that specific person after decoding with her matching private key (only she possesses).

Comment: Hm. That's a valid solution, but I guess it's not supported by the current ebook readers. Do you know if there is a solution which locks the document to someones reading device?

Comment: Linux/Android readers should be able to run `gpg`. For the ebook readers that support DRM you would have to go through their publisher to get that restriction added. Other ebook readers (the vast majority) do not support DRM, so you can change the books any way you want, but nothing will be checked. Any DRM scheme can be removed, whereas using `gpg` makes sure only the intended reader can read.

Comment: @Anthon although using gpg does not stop the recipient passing an unencrypted version on to another - depends what threat you are trying to overcome